# Why is 5 > 4 > 3 != (5 > 4 && 4 > 3) true in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Why is `5 > 4 > 3 != (5 > 4 && 4 > 3)` true in Javascript?

**So annoying!**

Comment: I'm curious which languages that IS true in. The only one I know of is Python.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`5 > 4 > 3` is evaluated like `(5 > 4) > 3`, then it's `true > 3`, which is `false`. [Look](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/8bFww/)

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript, in the great tradition of most languages that descend from C, does not support relational operator chaining.